# jQuery each not getting elements in child ul of parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My issue is this modifies the top level `li` `span` contents. When the `li` holds another `ul` inside it does not find those `span`s within. I thought the jQuery selector would get me all `".fancytree-node"` elements under my high level `div``.

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1. I've tried to change my selector and use many different methods but all gave me the same result as this jQuery statement.

jQuery and HTML:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#treeDestinationFancy .fancytree-icon").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
  });

  $("#treeDestinationFancy .fancytree-expander").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="treeDestinationFancy ">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
        <span class="fancytree-title">[Drag here]</span>
      <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
      <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
        <span class="fancytree-title">this item</span>
      <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
      <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="fancytree-lastsib">
      <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-expanded fancytree-has-children fancytree-lastsib fancytree-exp-el fancytree-ico-e">
        <span class="fancytree-title">Forward</span>
      <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
      <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
      </span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
          <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
          <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
          <span class="fancytree-title">Host with Protocol</span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
          <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
          <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
          <span class="fancytree-title">Audit Guid</span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
          <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
          <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
          <span class="fancytree-title">Contact:Email [InnerText]</span>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you define example for HTML output that u want ? Do you mean you want to get all `.fancytree-node` out to `#treeDestinationFancy`

Comment: You see how the spans are different in the top most li elements vs the ones nested in the last li? I just trying to flip the positions of the spans within that child ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm seeing what you're trying to do. You want each node to have the three children in the order "fancytree-title", "fancytree-icon", "fancytree-expander". You just need to change your selector so that it's selecting from the parent node, rather than the ancestor node.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".fancytree-node .fancytree-icon").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
  });

  $(".fancytree-node .fancytree-expander").each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="treeDestinationFancy ">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
        <span class="fancytree-title">[Drag here]</span>
        <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
        <span class="fancytree-title">this item</span>
        <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="fancytree-lastsib">
      <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-expanded fancytree-has-children fancytree-lastsib fancytree-exp-el fancytree-ico-e">
        <span class="fancytree-title">Forward</span>
        <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
      </span>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
            <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
            <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
            <span class="fancytree-title">Host with Protocol</span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
            <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
            <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
            <span class="fancytree-title">Audit Guid</span>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
            <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
            <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
            <span class="fancytree-title">Contact:Email [InnerText]</span>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but I tried it using a second Tree view on the same page and it does the same thing to that one and I need to have it only effect one tree at a time. You are correct but how do I constrain the selector to only one tree at a time?

Comment: Just checked again my actual code is a little different but in my environment this doesn't work. I may have a conflict I just don't know where.

Comment: But this does work with the code you've provided in the question, right? If you have a different question with different code, please ask that separately.

Comment: Well I tried to pull out the code in question from a small portion of what's rendered on page. I'll mark the answer for this one and continue to another. I just now realize this is not the issue at all I am having. This works and as been working just something is wrong with the page setup after getting this feed back and testing multiple times. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

ok.I got your issue. You must wrap every inner ULs with an LI, I had update code below.It is working fine.Please check.

```
<div id="treeDestinationFancy">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
                <span class="fancytree-title">[Drag here]</span>
                <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
                <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
                <span class="fancytree-title">this item</span>
                <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
                <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="fancytree-lastsib">
            <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-expanded fancytree-has-children fancytree-lastsib fancytree-exp-el fancytree-ico-e">
                <span class="fancytree-title">Forward</span>
                <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
                <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
            </span>
            <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
                        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
                        <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
                        <span class="fancytree-title">Host with Protocol</span>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
                        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
                        <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
                        <span class="fancytree-title">Audit Guid</span>
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
                        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
                        <img class="fancytree-icon" alt="" src="/Images.gif">
                        <span class="fancytree-title">Contact:Email [InnerText]</span>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a slight copy pasta mistake my bad. But even with the space I still cannot get it to hit any node under the ul list within the last main li.

Comment: i edited the code as per your concern.It is working fine now. You must wrap every inner ULs with an LI

Comment: An `li` cannot contain another `li`. The `li` should wrap the `ul`. All this code does is change the hierarchy so that the second `ul` is now under a sibling of the `li class="fancytree-lastsib"`

Comment: Yeah this seems like messy HTML I couldn't do this regardless. It would  throw off my CSS code for this tree.